# trying to use a function to populate a HTML table dynamically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a table that populates fine with javascript and Ajax, but now I need to add in checkboxes and have them show checked if saved in the database that way (1 for checked 0 for not).  Instead of writing

```
 var aChecked='';
 aChecked += '<input type="checkbox" id="amS"'+(data.amS == 1 ? 'checked="checked"':'')+'/>';
```

for every checkbox ( there are about 24 of them) I am trying to use a modified function that I use to see if other checkboxes not in the table are checked.  The function is:

```
function Checked(){
this.update();
}
```

is above my $.ajax and this is in my success(function(data) portion.

```
Checked.prototype.list = ['am','fol','tich','book','neb','ster','byte','ing'];
Checked.prototype.update = function(){
for( var i = 0 ; i < this.list.length ; i++ ){
var check = this.list[i];
this[ check + 'S' ] += '<input type="checkbox" id="'+this[ check + 'S' ]+'"'+(data.this[ check + 'S' ] == 1 ? 'checked="checked"':'')+'/>';//$("#" + check ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
                      }// end of for loop  
                    }
                    var checks = new Checked();
```

and then I can reference it in my append statement like so

```
<td>'+checks.amS+'</td>
```

Problem is I am getting this error when I try to run it:

```
TypeError: data.this is undefined
```

I am not sure how i need to write this in order for this to work and not have to write it out the long way and violate the DRY principle.  I have tried

```
data.(this[ check + 'S' ])
```

and

```
data.[this[ check + 'S' ]]
```

both of which throw syntax errors.  Anyone know how I can accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: try `var foo = data[this[ check + 'S' ]]`  (remove the dot)

Comment: when I put data[this[ check + 'S' ]] == 1 and then use console.log(checks.amS) I get undefined.

Comment: I'd suggest you throw out all your code and start over again, but only after reading up on basic JS concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this[ check + 'S' ] += '<input type="checkbox" ... >'  
// this[ check + 'S' ] = this[ check + 'S' ] + '<input type="checkbox" ... >'
// this[ check + 'S' ] = undefined + '<input type="checkbox" ...  >'
```

to

```
this[ check + 'S' ] = '<input type="checkbox" ... >'
```

Check your code plz

```
this[ check + 'S' ] =
    '<input type="checkbox" id="'+this[ check + 'S' ]+'"' // this[ check + 'S' ] is undefined
     +(data.this[ check + 'S' ] == 1 ? 'checked="checked"':'')+'/>'; // this[ check + 'S' ] is undefined
     //$("#" + check ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

to

```
this[ check + 'S' ] =
    '<input type="checkbox" id="'+check + 'S'+'"' // modified
     +(data[ check + 'S' ] == 1 ? 'checked="checked"':'')+'/>'; // modified
     //$("#" + check ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

"this" means "var checks" on your update function in this case

"data[this]" is really wrong access,

why this means object(instance) not string(object's key)

Comment: when i do that and use console.log(checks) I get the ID as undefined, but it is setting the initial this[ check+'S' ].

Comment: That was it!!  Thank you very much for the help unlike @torazaburo